# Deploy Laravel app in Apache server and Vue not working

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js

after having deployed my laravel application on apache server everything works correctly except the Vue component in the console I have this error:

after having deployed my laravel application on apache server everything works correctly except the Vue component in the console I have this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise / async): "Error: Network Error"

found in

---> <IndexComponent> at resources / js / components / IndexComponent.vue
       <Root>

warn @ app.js: 39060
logError @ app.js: 40332
globalHandleError @ app.js: 40327
handleError @ app.js: 40287
(anonymous) @ app.js: 40304
Promise.catch (async)
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js: 40304
callHook @ app`enter code here`.js: 42669enter code here
insert @ app.js: 41595
invokeInsertHook @ app.js: 44822
patch @ app.js: 45041
Vue._update @ app.js: 42394
updateComponent @ app.js: 42515
get @ app.js: 42929
Watcher @ app.js: 42918
mountComponent @ app.js: 42522
Vue. $ Mount @ app.js: 47528
Vue. $ Mount @ app.js: 50442
Vue._init @ app.js: 43462
Vue @ app.js: 43529
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js: 2203
__webpack_require__ @ app.js: 50486
(anonymous) @ app.js: 50651
__webpack_require __. O @ app.js: 50523
(anonymous) @ app.js: 50653
(anonymous) @ app.js: 50655
app.js: 40336 Error: Network Error
    at createError (app.js: 607)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (app.js: 104)
```

IndexComponent code

```
<script>
export default {
  props: { selected: Number, specializations: Array },
  data() {
    return {
      specId: this.selected,
      doctors: [],
      results: true,
      scTimer: 0,
      scY: 0,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    return this.filterSpec();
  },

  watch: {
    specId: function () {
      return this.filterSpec();
    },
  },

  methods: {
    sponsDoc: function (arr) {
      // Set slice() to avoid to generate an infinite loop!
      return arr.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.att - a.att;
      });
    },
    
    filterSpec: function () {
      return await axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/doctors?specialization=" + this.specId)
        .then((resp) => {
          this.doctors = resp.data;
          // console.log(this.doctors);
          this.doctors.forEach((doctor) => {
            doctor.sponAtt = [];

            var currentDate = new Date();

            doctor.sponsors.forEach((spon) => {
              spon.end = spon.pivot.expiration_time;
              if (new Date(spon.end) > new Date(currentDate)) {
                doctor.sponAtt.push(spon);
              } else {
              }
              // console.log(spon.end);
            });

            doctor.att = doctor.sponAtt.length;

            doctor.spec = [];
            doctor.num = doctor.reviews.length;

            var sum = doctor.reviews.reduce((acc, rew) => acc + rew.vote, 0);
            // console.log(sum);
            var avarage = sum / doctor.num;
            if (Number.isNaN(avarage)) {
              doctor.avarage = 0;
            } else {
              doctor.avarage = avarage.toFixed(2);
            }

            doctor.specializations.forEach((spec) => {
              doctor.spec.push(spec.name);
            });
          });
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please can you add the code for your `IndexComponent` to your question.

Comment: locally works perfectly